# I have a text-area where, how can you use <h1>, <strong> tags within it when in the web browser?

Tags: css, html

I have a text-area where users would add text, how can I allow user to use tags within the text-area to change the style of the text?
For example user wants to make one line stand out so he would use  tag within the text-area provided.

Comment: The users can enter what ever they ( or you ) want. What you do with this data is your choice. You could for example just `echo` the value with php.

Comment: What you are looking for is this: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/

Comment: you must parse it using js if this should be really `textarea` otherwise you can use an html editor inplace

Comment: You could use a content edible div. That would allow for formatting within the div and allows editing of text inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want user to be able to add just the tags you can directly use appendchild() method and append the content to the DOM.

Else, if you want a full blown "Rich Text Input or Textarea" :

You can check out [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) for an editor / preview example.

Also, you can check out [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) which is used by StackOverflow to format user text.

Other options are [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) and [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a preview HTML element, just like what *stackoverflow* does in the questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of javascript.  As you have the textarea , allow users to type in the content with the html tags . Now use jquery or javascript to append the content to DOM.

example:

```
   var textContent= $('#textArea').val();
    $('body').append(textContent)
```